# Preview Microsoft Word in Greyscale?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, grayscale, print-preview

If I have a Microsoft Word document with colour images, but I have a monochrome printer, how can I preview the document in greyscale to verify what the printed document will look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a late reply, but I wanted to share the method that I use for future reference. I found it useful to instead of changing the document's color scheme, just change the display to greyscale.

I use an nVidia graphics card, in order to do this go to desktop, right click -> nVidia Control panel -> adjust desktop color settings (left tab) -> set "Digital Vibrance" at 0.

This is a little cumbersome, but is better than changing the entire document by hand.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to previewing in Microsoft Word, but it's a great workaround, and definitely the best answer in almost two years! A more general solution that should be compatible with most video cards (mine is Intel) is to set "Saturation" on the video card to 0; that has the effect of setting all colours to greyscale. This lets me preview the document (or anything else on my screen) in greyscale and then change back the settings when I'm done.

Answer (score 3):

Using Word 2013 I cannot get the print preview to show in grayscale.

One thing I was able to do is save it as a PDF file via CutePDF and then use Acrobat Reader's print dialogue to preview the document in grayscale.

I know it's a somewhat lengthy workaround but it's better than nothing :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get the print preview to show in grayscale.
However, I have another suggestion on top of the one provided by MonkeyZeus.
This may not be an efficient way to do this depending on how many pictures you have in your document.  If you only have a few, you can change the color of each photo to 'greyscale' by double clicking the picture, which brings up the Picture Tools.  Click on the color button and choose greyscale.
That should give you a good idea of what it will look like when printed.
Hope this helps!
[image: What the buttons look like in Word 2010]

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution that works. Right click on start menu, hit settings, ease of access -> colour filters, then turn on colour filters and set the filter to be grayscale.

Comment: Is that in Word or do you mean the Windows settings?

Comment: I'm talking about the Windows setting here. I'm not sure if there's an equivalent for Mac/Linux, I suspect there should be.

Comment: This solved it for me. Although at the time of writing, for Windows 10 you don't need to go through ease of access - you just need to go Settings -> type in 'Colour filters' to get there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify specific pictures, you can select the picture then:

- Right click->Format picture
- Go to the tab with the image icon.
- Expand the "Colour tone" area.
- Then you can set the saturation for the picture to 0.

When you are done, there is a preset to reset it to 100 in the icon that looks like a coat-hanger.